# How to manage many printers in office?\

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

I have some printers in my offices, I have multi-team (200 colleagues) working together at the same time. User need to use printer to print documents.
I want to know:
1. Who using what printer, and what's printing (document name, page count)?
2. Is there any printer got problem (paper stuck, ink empty) 
How can I archive it? 
I'm using Epson 1390 and Epson L1800

Answer (score 1):

[PaperCut](https://www.papercut.com/) offers nearly everything that is related to monitoring printers, like

- tracking activity
- queue management
- printer security
- printer health notification
- printer failure prevention
- and so on..